# c# forms search in database

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm trying to make a program that shows user information from my database and i need to make a search function in c# that connects to my database.

Example: User can search for his `UserID` and get his information (mail, phone nr and so on)

What I have tried:

```
    private void søg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connectionString = @"Data source=WIN-6147SKCOSR7;Initial Catalog=TEC;User ID=sqlhelper; Password=admin1234";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        cnn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM bruger WHERE UserID LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'", cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter adtp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adtp.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

Not 1 time have I've got information displayed on my dataGridView.

I have tried other Stackoverflow answers without luck, my brain is on the verge to shutting down

Note: I'm running on a Virtual Machine

Comment: Do you get any exceptions when the code runs?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you run your code in the debugger? Have you put break points in the code that you have posted? Does the debugger hit the breakpoints? Do you get any exceptions? etc..

Comment: at least you should debug the code. Set a breakpoint after `cnn.Open();` and check if this was working

Comment: I have set breakpoint on cnn.Open() and adtp.Fill(dt), both get "hit"

Comment: My debugger dont show any problems or mistakes

Comment: When using the debugger, does the `textBox1.Text` variable contain any value if you hoover the mouse pointer over it? After the SQL is executed, does the `dt` variable contain any rows?

Comment: The textBox1 contain the value for what i search for - and it seems that dt dont contain any rows

Comment: Take the final value of the query string (after you've included the textbox content), run it in SQL Management Studio, and see if you get any results.

Comment: My query works when i remove the 2 %

Comment: So it only says: SELECT * FROM bruger WHERE UserID LIKE 'ande1234'

Comment: OT you should not include user input in your sql command string like this, use parameters. Look up "sql injection"

Comment: im aware of this but this is just for a school project where we need to learn the basics with sql and c# but thank u anyway for pointing it out :))

Comment: Let's hope [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) is not using the software

Comment: "the query works without %" - in SSMS or your code (or both)? Anything special about the definition of that UserID column?

Comment: in SSMS - there isnt anythin special about the column

Comment: What is the datatype of the UserID column?